# How to test image carousel in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, unit-testing, testing

I am creating an image carousel component, see below:

### ImageSlider

```
 import React,{useState} from 'react'
import {BsChevronCompactLeft,BsChevronCompactRight} from 'react-icons/bs'

function ImageSlider({images}) {

  const [currentIndex, setCurrentState] = useState(0);
  const length = images.length;

  const prevImage = () => {
    const isFirstSlide = currentIndex === 0
    const newIndex = isFirstSlide ? length - 1 : currentIndex - 1
    setCurrentState(newIndex)
  }
  
  const nextImage = () => {
    const isLastSlide = currentIndex === length - 1
    const newIndex = isLastSlide ? 0 : currentIndex + 1 
    setCurrentState(newIndex)
  }
  
  return (
    <div className='max-w-[800px] h-[500px] w-full m-auto py-16 px-4 relative'>
    {/* <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className='left-arrow' onClick={prevImage}> 
  </FaArrowAltCircleLeft>
    <FaArrowAltCircleRight className='right-arrow' onClick={nextImage}></FaArrowAltCircleRight> */}
      <div 
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url("${images[currentIndex]}")` }}  
      className='w-full h-full rounded-2xl bg-center bg-cover duration-500'
    >

      </div>
      <div className='absolute top-50% -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] left-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer'>
        <BsChevronCompactLeft size={30} onClick={prevImage}></BsChevronCompactLeft>
      </div>
      <div className='absolute top-50% -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] right-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer'>
        <BsChevronCompactRight size={30} onClick={nextImage}></BsChevronCompactRight>
      </div>


    </div>
  )
}
```

export default ImageSlider

---

it gets passed images. However, I can't seem to be able to test if the image is rendered or not, and if the buttons work to change images.

### I have tried

```
 import ImageSlider from "./component/ImageSlider" 
    import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react"
    import React from "react"
    import image1 from "./image1.jpg"
    import image2 from "./image2.jpg"
    
    test('should render images', () => {
      const images = [image1, image2];
      render(<ImageSlider images={images} role='img'/>);
      const img = screen.getAllByTestId("img");
      expect(img).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

// test('should navigate to the next image', () => {
//   const images = [image1, image2];
//   render(<ImageSlider images={images} />);
//   fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Next'));
//   expect(screen.getByAltText('image2')).toBeInTheDocument();
// });

// test('should navigate to the previous image', () => {
//   const images = [image1, image2];
//   render(<ImageSlider images={images} />);
//   fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Previous'));
//   expect(screen.getByAltText('image2')).toBeInTheDocument();
// });
```

But there doesn't seem to be very good resources on image unit testing online. any help would be appreciated.